# Error while running rake zeitwerk:check in a model by inheriting a class from a rails engine as a gem in Rails 6 app using Zeitwerk Loader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload, rails-engines, zeitwerk

I am using a Rails Engine as a Gem in my Rails Application. Now I have inherited a class from the rails engine in a model of my rails app.

1. **Rails App Model Code**

```
class AppModelOne < EngineGem::EngineClassOne
   # body of the class
end
```

But while running the command 
`rake zeitwerk:check` 
 in terminal, I got a error that 
 *uninitialised constant <class:32323332xx> EngineModuleTwo* 
 Now I checked the rails engine code of EngineClassOne in which there is a include statement of EngineModuleTwo.

2. **Rails Engine Class Code**

```
module EngineGem
  class EngineClassOne
     include EngineModuleTwo::EngineSubModuleOne
  end
end
```

The Engine file-structure:

```
  EngineGem -> |-> app     -> models |-> engine_gem         -> engine_class_one
               |                     |-> engine_module_two  -> engine_sub_module_one
               |-> gemspec
```

Why it is not able to load the module, Can anyone explain how to load the module inside the rails engine while using it in my rails app?

Comment: `include` is used to mix the contents of a module into a class. You can't use `include` when the target is another class. If `EngineClassTwo` is indeed a class, that's an error and zeitwerk will complain.

Comment: You can see this if you run a rails console in the engine gem. Instantiating an instance of `EngineGem::EngineClassOne` will raise an error.

Comment: By default we can't open a rails console in engine right @rmlockerd

Comment: Yes @rmlockerd , Inside EngineClassOne I am including a module , I have updated the question, Kindly have a look, and suggest any solution.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error as you have it specified now. What options did you use to create your engine? `--full`?

Comment: @rmlockerd I am using a existing engine made by someone else. Can you specify any settings/config which will  help you out to identify.